# Mock bean is autowired into @Spy bean mockito

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

My unit test try @Spy beanA. But BeanA  @autowire bean B as bellow:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyServiceImplTest {
    @Spy
    private BeanA beanA;
    
    @InjectMocks
    private MyService myService = new MyServiceImpl();


   @Test
   public void testDoSomeThing(){
        myService.doSomeThing();
   }
}
```

MyServiceImpl as bellow :

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl {
    
    @Autowired
    private BeanA beanA;
    
    public doSomeThing(){
        ....
        beanA.beanADoSomeThing()
        ....
    }
}
```

beanA  as bellow

```
@Service
public class BeanA {
    
    @Autowired
    private BeanB beanB;
    
    public beanADoSomeThing(){
        ...
        //Null pointer exception in here because beanB=null
        beanB.beanBDoSomeThing()
    }
}
```

when run unit test i get null pointer exception at line `beanB.beanBDoSomeThing()`, I can understand the reason but how to resolve this issue?

I have tried

```
@Mock
private BeanB beanB;
```

But this not work, how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: So you are using mockito and wonder why spring autowiring doesn't work?

Comment: All Mockito mocks return default values for primitive types or `null` if you don't stub the behavior of your mocks. Consider this [@Mock vs. @MockBean](https://rieckpil.de/difference-between-mock-and-mockbean-spring-boot-applications/) explanation. Next, please update your question with the intent of your test

Answer (score 1):

If you want to spy your bean in context, you need `@SpyBean` annotation instead of `@Spy` and also you should autowire your service to be tested, smth like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ExTest {

    @SpyBean
    private BeanA beanA;

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;


    @Test
    public void testDoSomeThing() {
        myService.doSomeThing();
    }
}
```

If you don't want to load application context and test only `MyServiceImpl` behavior in isolation, you can use pure Mockito and mock or spy dependencies of `MyServiceImpl`:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockitTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private MyServiceImpl myService;

    @Mock
    private BeanA beanA;

    @Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
    public void test() {
        
        doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(beanA).beanADoSomeThing();
        
        myService.doSomeThing();
    }
}
```